# Zenity list find results

Tags: shell, find, zenity

I am trying to make a list of all `find` results but it gets all results as one option. How to make every result different option to choose and store it in `CHOICE`?

```
CHOICE=$(zenity --list --title "Choose file:" --column=Files "$(find $DIRECTORY -name "*.cpp")")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too many quotes:

```
zenity --list --title "Choose file:" --column=Files $(find $DIRECTORY -name "*.h")
```

The double quotes around `"$(find)"` make the result a **single** very long filename, when instead you want to use word-splitting to make them separate files. Note that you will have problems with filenames containing white-space.

Comment: "Note that you will have problems with filenames containing white-space."... so, it's not a complete answer ! Any help for this ?